# JavaScriptで、Webページ内の指定DOM要素以下だけをブラウザキャッシュ出来ますか？

Tags: javascript

Webページ内で、キャッシュしたい画像とキャッシュしたくない画像があるのですが、
例えば、指定DOM要素以下だけ(の画像)をキャッシュ指定出来ますか？

Comment: サーバーサイドで画像ファイルごとに `Cache-Control` ヘッダーを付与ではなく、条件はDOMベースでしか判定できませんか？サーバーサイドで制御にしろ、Service Workerで制御にしろ、URLベース判定であれば簡潔です。

Comment: 同一URLのWebページを表示する際、「キャッシュする画像」と「キャッシュしない画像」を指定する方法であれば何でも良いです(特にDOM要素に拘っているわけではありません)。「サーバーサイドで画像ファイルごとに Cache-Control ヘッダーを付与」はどうやるのですか？　また「URLベース判定」の意味が分からないのですが、URLごとに「キャッシュするURL」と「キャッシュしないURL」を指定するという意味であれば、私がやりたいこととは違います。

Comment: 例えば特定のディレクトリにある画像だけキャッシュしないという基準ならほとんどのサーバーでキャッシュ可否を設定できます。 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407 もっと複雑な条件があるのでしたら、どういうHTMLと画像ファイルの構成でどうしたいか具体例あると誰か答えられるかもしれません。